# Listings show Quotation marks in italic - how to print them in Regular?

Tags: listings, fontspec, italic, sourcecode

I use the `listings` package for showing source code. I just realized, that double and single quotation marks are printed in *italic* - they should be printed in **regular** instead ... Where is the issue? Is there a config I've overseen?

Any ideas? Thanks for your inputs!

[image]

I defined my own listing style like this:

```
\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{backcolour}{HTML}{F5F5F5}

\lstdefinestyle{codestyle}{
    backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},   
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{magenta},
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
    stringstyle=\color{codepurple},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    breakatwhitespace=false,         
    breaklines=true,                 
    captionpos=b,                    
    keepspaces=true,                 
    numbers=left,                    
    numbersep=5pt,                  
    showspaces=false,                
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,                  
    tabsize=2
}

\lstset{style=codestyle}
```

I also load the Jetbrains-MonoFont (can be downloaded [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/de-de/lp/mono/)):

```
%JetBrains Mono-Font für Code
\setmonofont{JetBrains Mono}[
    Path = ./Fonts/Code/,
    Extension = .ttf,
    UprightFont = *-Regular,
    BoldFont = *-Bold,
    ItalicFont = *-Italic,
    BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic,
    Contextuals = Alternate,
    Ligatures = TeX,
]
\lstset{
    basicstyle = \ttfamily,
    columns = flexible,
}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\verbatim@nolig@list{}
\makeatother
```

Complete document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, liststotoc]{scrreprt}

%Packages
\usepackage[bmargin=4cm,tmargin=2cm,headheight=5cm]{geometry} %Seitenränder definieren
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage[colorlinks, urlcolor=blue, linkcolor=black, citecolor=black]{hyperref}
\usepackage[german, noabbrev, nameinlink]{cleveref} %Automatische Verweise mit \cref{} oder \cpageref{} auf \label{}. Bei englischer Arbeit muss "german" durch "english" ersetzt werden. 
\usepackage{float} %Unterdrückt das Fliessen eines Bildes wenn statt "h" "H" als float angegeben wird.
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[round, comma, sort&compress]{natbib} %Bibliografie
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{listings}
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------%
%Konfigurationen

%JetBrains Mono-Font für Code
\setmonofont{JetBrains Mono}[
    Path = ./Fonts/Code/,
    Extension = .ttf,
    UprightFont = *-Regular,
    BoldFont = *-Bold,
    ItalicFont = *-Italic,
    BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic,
    Contextuals = Alternate,
    Ligatures = TeX,
]
\lstset{
    basicstyle = \ttfamily,
    columns = flexible,
}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\verbatim@nolig@list{}
\makeatother


\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{backcolour}{HTML}{F5F5F5}

\lstdefinestyle{codestyle}{
    backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},   
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{magenta},
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
    stringstyle=\color{codepurple},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    breakatwhitespace=false,         
    breaklines=true,                 
    captionpos=b,                    
    keepspaces=true,                 
    numbers=left,                    
    numbersep=5pt,                  
    showspaces=false,                
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,                  
    tabsize=2
}

\lstset{style=codestyle}


%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------%
\begin{document}


\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python, caption=Python example]
import numpy as np
    
@property
    def serialize(self):
        """Return object data in easily serializeable format"""
        return {
            'id': self.id,
            'name': self.name,
            'description': self.description,
            'program_type': self.program_type,
            'url': self.url,
            'auth': self.auth.serialize
        }

\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The option `Ligatures = TeX` for `\setmonofont` is most probaby the culprit, since it will map `"` [Quotation Mark, U+0022] to `”` [Right Double Quotation Mark, U+201D] (which is rendered like a slanted `"` in the font you use). Nice choice of font! +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quotation marks are not printed in italic, but they are replaced by `”` (RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK, U+201D). This is, because you told `fontspec` to enable the TeX ligatures for the monospace font and one of these so-called ligatures exactly does this replacement. The character `”` (U+201D) is rendered like slanted quotation marks (not only) in the font you chose. The same is true for `'` and `’` (RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK, U+2019).

If you comment out the option `Ligatures = TeX` for `\setmonofont`, you will get the following output:

[image]